# How to pop up the EditText box when button is tapped,objective c,ios

Tags: ios, button, popup, tap

How to pop up the Edit Text box when the button is tapped using objective c.Am trying to do but i want some help.Can some body provide some samples for me.I made googling but am not able to find the solution.Please some body help me?

Comment: i want to enter some text when the edit text box is poped up

Comment: What do you mean? What EditText box? What button? You need to post more details and try to be clearer. Your question is not easy to understand as it is right now

Comment: Hi boss.Thanks for replying.Not edit text box,UITextView,when i click a RoundRect button,UITextView is to be displayed

Comment: In the sense when i tap a button,UITextView need to be popd up for user to enter some text

Comment: So you have a button and when you press that button you want an UITextView to be displayed inside an UIPopoverController?

Comment: yes you understood ma question Bodgan Bucur

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this is rather easy if I understood correctly what you need.

First, you need to make a new UIViewController, called let's say TextViewController

Inside TextViewController you place your UITextView, making it as big as you need, changing the font or whatever you might need/want.

After this all you need to do is to present TextViewController inside an UIPopoverController ( http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPopoverController_class/Reference/Reference.html )
The code should look something like this

> TextViewController* textViewController = [[TextViewController alloc] init];
>
> UIPopoverController* aPopover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:textViewController];
>
> aPopover.popoverContentSize = CGSizeMake(320.0,110.0); //sets the size of the popover
>
> [aPopover presentPopoverFromRect:yourButton.frame inView:self permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];

where textViewController is the view controller with the UITextView and yourButton is the rounded button you tap on.

This tutorial should also be useful: http://www.raywenderlich.com/1056/ipad-for-iphone-developers-101-uipopovercontroller-tutorial